# Bijection between $\text{Hom}_G(\mathbb{C}[G],V)$ and $V$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $(\mathbb{C}[G], \rho_\text{reg})$ the regular representation. I need to show that for any representation $(V, \rho)$ of $G$ there is a bijection from $\text{Hom}_G(\mathbb{C}[G],V)$ to $V$.

My attempts are:

I want to show that $\forall v \in V$ there is a unique $\varphi \in \text{Hom}_G(\mathbb{C}[G],V)$ such that $\varphi(e) = v $. I managed to show that $\varphi( \sum_{g \in G} a_g g) = \sum_{g \in G} \rho(g) (v)$ satisfies this condition, but I am not sure how to show that this is the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\phi(e)=\phi'(e)=v$ implies that $\phi(g)=\phi(g.1)=\rho(g)\phi(1)=\rho(g).v$ and $\phi'(g)=\phi'(g.1)=\rho(g)\phi'(1)=\rho(g).v$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! why is $\varphi(g \cdot 1) = \rho(g) \varphi(1)$?

Comment: Because it is a morphism of representations

Comment: I see that $\varphi(g \cdot 1) = \varphi(g) \varphi(1)$, but why is $\varphi(g) = \rho(g)$?

Comment: $\phi(g)$ is not equal to $\rho(g)$, it is the action of $G$ on $G$ by left multiplication which is transformed to $\phi$, write $L_g(x)=g.x$ in $G$, $\phi\circ L_g=\rho(g)\circ \phi$.